# Залипает весь сервер при бесконечном цикле

Tags: php, javascript, apache, docker, server-side-events

Имеется:

- Docker последний
- [php:5.6-apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)

Вот этот простой код (sse.php):

```
<?php
// Set necessary headers
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Connection: keep-alive');


$lastId = 0;
while (true) {
    $lastId++;
    sendMessage($lastId, rand(1, 99));

    sleep(1);
}

// Function to send data in format "ticket:price".
function sendMessage($id, $data)
{
    echo "id: $id\n";
    echo "data: $data\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Если в консоли ввести вот эту команду:

```
curl http://localhost/sse.php
```

В консоли будут выводиться правильные данные (пример):

```
id: 1
data: 41

id: 2
data: 12

id: 3
data: 7

id: 4
data: 10
```

Но если в браузере перейти по ссылке http://localhost/index.php, то ее не открыть. Как-будто пытается подключиться, но безуспешно:

[image: Вечная загрузка]

Если сбросить процесс curl (`Ctrl+C`), через мгновение страница подгрузится и все хорошо.

Такая же ситуация, когда я пытаюсь запустить вот это:

```
var eventSource = new EventSource('/sse.php');
eventSource.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log("Пришло сообщение: " + e.data);
};
```

Все работает замечательно:

[image: Все работает замечательно]

Подключение создается, но другие страницы не открываются от слова совсем.

После `eventSource.close()` все загружается.

В чем может быть проблема? Какую еще информацию предоставить? Как можно исправить эту неприятную проблему в рамках выбранных технологий?

**UPDATE:**

Попытался добавить в конфиг apache вот эти строки из интернета, погоды это не изменило:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit              250
    StartServers              10
    MinSpareThreads           75
    MaxSpareThreads          250
    ThreadLimit               64
    ThreadsPerChild           32
    MaxRequestWorkers       8000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 10000
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Так как по историческим причинам в проекте используется Yii2, подобная логика была перенесена в action:

```
public function sendMessage($id, $data)
{
    $content = "id: $id\n";
    $content .= "data: $data\n\n";

    $response = Yii::$app->response;
    $response->content = $content;
    $response->send();
    $response->clear();
    flush();
}

public function actionIndex()
{
    $response = Yii::$app->response;

    $response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    $response->headers->set('Connection', 'keep-alive');

    $lastId = 0;
    while (true) {
        $lastId++;
        $this->sendMessage($lastId, rand(1, 99));

        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Работает все также плохо. Другие страницы открываться не хотят. Начинаю грешить на docker. Хотя могу и ошибаться... Очень нужна ваша помощь

Comment: А какое максимальное количество подключений в настройках вашего apache? Может быть в этом причина.

Comment: @Torv конфиг апача почти дефолтный, только конфиг default сайта был изменен. Попытался добавить несколько строк в конфиг, которые нашел в интернете, ничего не изменилось (обновил вопрос, секция UPDATE)

Comment: Если рассуждать здраво, то причина кроется в том, что вебсервер обрабатывает один запрос и не может обработать второй, и тот отваливается с 504 ошибкой. Это может быть либо по причине неправилньой настройки самого вебсервера, либо некорректных настроек прослоек. К сожалению помочь конкретнее ничем не могу. Возможно вам поможет [вот этот вопрос](https://serverfault.com/questions/841918/nginx-docker-dotnet-app-on-ubuntu-16-04-request-timeout/841992#841992)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема тут скорее всего с сессиями. По дефолту сессии блокируются для каждого вызова скрипта пользователя. Вы создаете бесконечный скрипт он бесконечно блокирует сесиию и все другие запросы от этого же пользователя не могут получить к ней доступ поэтому бесконечно ее ждут. Можно отключить блокирование сессий но это может привести к ошибкам при ее затирании конкурентными запросами, но для проверки теории можно.

Или можно использовать session_write_close();
Вообще можно погуглить PHP Session Locks

Comment: Спасибо. Пока не пробовал, но звучит здраво

Comment: Вы гений. Спасибо большое, это решило проблему целиком и полностью. Также частично виновником проблемы был xdebug с автоматическим удаленным подключением.

Comment: Забавно, что в английском SO ответа мне не дали. Спасибо большое еще раз